# UbuntuStudio WineHQ doesn't work because system says the wineprefix is wrong

Tags: permissions, wine, 64-bit, winetricks

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3 LTS 64 bit installation.

I uninstalled and re-installed Wine, yesterday (Sunday, Sept. 5, 2021), to try to fix some problems.

And... Yesterday all about Wine worked so fine!

Today (monday), I powered-on my PC, all the system started so fine, but... Wine doesn't work, here, now!

I just get this error message:

> wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message
> "wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/jjpg/.wine' is a 64-bit
> installation."

That message is so weird because I tested the /etc/enviroment file and I can cleary read:

> WINEPREFIX=win64

So, I opened a terminal and used the sudo privilege to change this with:

> WINEPREFIX="home/.wine" WINEPREFIX=win64 wine wineboot

But... Even the fact I'm the only one SuperUser here, I got the following message:

> wine: '/home/jjpg/.wine' is not owned by you

So...

How could it be possible the system tells I'm not the owner of myself installation if I opened that terminal with my sudo privileges?

What's wrong here?

Is there some other way to change that "WINEPREFIX" from  32 to 64 bit? How?

Comment: Read carefully. It's complaining about "`WINEARCH`", not"`WINEPREFIX`" .

Comment: @waltinator Thank You So Much!!! It was my fault. Sorry!!!